# How to add an icon in right side of taskbar with batch

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch

does anyone know how I can make new icon in right part of taskbar? But not as a program, I want create a normal icon like for example from teamspeak3, and if it possible with options too. And also, if it is possible with batch, that will be awesome

Comment: You mean like a System Tray icon?

Comment: @MichaelFrank that's what it seems like they are asking about...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479842/batch-icon-message-on-task-bar is probably what you want. But it's super ugly from batch scripting